# find the equation of tangent to circle at $x^2+y^2-60y-80x+2100=0$

Tags: analytic-geometry

I proceed by assuming parametric coordinate $x=20 \cos t+40,y=20 \sin t+30$. And write equation of tangent at parametric point $(t)$. And then write distance of origin from tangent and minimize distance to solve for $t$. To find the given point but it comes out to be incorrect. What mistake I
made.

Comment: It's hard to know without seeing some of your working, and the answer you got, and how that compares to the answer that you should have gotten. Can you add any of that information?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. A question should be written in such a way that it can be understood even by someone who did not read the title.

Comment: @AtharJamal also , use mathjax to type in commands

Comment: The tangent to the circle from where?

Comment: Expand $$(x+40+20\cos(t))^2+(y+30+20\sin(t))^2-60(y+30+20\sin(t))-80(x+40+20\cos(t))+2100=0$$ to get $$x^2+y^2+40\sin(t)y+40\cos(t)x=0$$ i.e. $$40\sin(t)(y-30-20\sin(t))+40\cos(t)(x-40-20\cos(t))=0$$ is your tangent at the parametric point.